# is there a way to realize only write once list for the judgement?

Tags: javascript

I have a function you can see the bellow:

I want the param `use_five`:

```
function put_list(use_five) {
  if (use_five) {
    return [{name:"a"}, {name: "asxsa"}, {name: "ABC"}, {name: "Well"}, {name: "5"}]
  }else {
    return [{name:"a"}, {name: "asxsa"}, {name: "ABC"}, {name: "Well"}]
  }

}
```

if is `true`, I return:

```
[{name:"a"}, {name: "asxsa"}, {name: "ABC"}, {name: "Well"}, {name: "5"}]
```

if is `false`, I return:

```
[{name:"a"}, {name: "asxsa"}, {name: "ABC"}, {name: "Well"}]
```

I know I can use a if-else for judgement, but I do not want do that, because in my practical project there are lots items in the list.

so, is there a way to realize it by one line instead of write two lines of list?

Comment: Have you learned about `for` loops yet?

Comment: which count do you want beside the five parts?

Comment: @Thomas there is no rule of the list's items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function put_list(use_five) {
  let result = [{name:"1"}, {name: "2"}, {name: "3"}, {name: "4"}];
  if (use_five) {
    result.push({name:"5"});
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't begin to guess what you are really after, but here is one way to cut down on repetition:

```
function put_list(use_five) {
  var items = [{name:"a"}, {name: "asxsa"}, {name: "ABC"}, {name: "Well"}];
  if (use_five) {
    items.push({name: "5"});
  }
  return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could slice the array for the wanted count of elements.

```js
function getList(take5) {
    var data = [{ name: "1" }, { name: "2" }, { name: "3" }, { name: "4" }, { name: "5" }];
    return data.slice(0, take5 ? 5 : 4);
}

console.log(getList());
console.log(getList(true));
```